# Using number_format in a loop

Tags: php

I am running a for loop 10 times in order to populate data in a data table. In doing this, I wanted to use number_format in order to format the numbers. However, when I apply the number_format the For loop for some reason runs one additional time.

It works just fine when I exclude the number_format. Can anyone explain why this happens?

```
<?php
  foreach($data['data'] as $result) {
    For ($n = 0; $n <= 10; $n++){
      echo "<td>";
      echo number_format($result[$n], 0, ".", ",");
      echo "</td>";
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Most likely one of the $result[$n] is NULL and number_format would error out.

Comment: You say "loop 10 times" but you're starting at 0 and including 10 so it's 11 loops (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10). Use `$n < 10` if you only want it to run 10 times (assuming you're starting from 0 with `$n = 0`)

Comment: Thank you both. @h2ooooooo you are of course correct. My '10' is just an example. However, I believe my for loop is implemented correctly since when I don't include the formatting it returns all of the output I'm looking for. Only when I do the number_format does it include one additional figure (a zero).

Comment: @ChartProblems, can you post both current and expected output here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Your loop will always run an additional time. Assuming that there are no errors in your `number_format` function call, all you have to do to get this to run 10 times is change your code to `for($n = 0; $n < 10; n++)`. Note the use of `<` and not `<=`.

`For` loops are really just syntactical sugar for `while` loops. The statement `for(initial_statement; bound_condition; loop_statement) { code; }` is equivalent to

```
initial_statement;
while(bound_condition) {
    code;
    loop_statement;
}
```

Which, functionally, is equivalent to

```
initial_statement;
while(true) {
    code;
    loop_statement;
    if(!bound_condition) break;
}
```

This means that if you want a loop to run, say, 2 times, and you write `for($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++)` your code will loop as follows:

**$i = 0**

`i++;` (`i` now equals `1`)

`i <= 2` (condition is `true`, so continue)

**$i = 1**

`i++;` (`i` now equals `2`)

`i <= 2` (condition is `true`, so continue)

**$i = 2**

`i++;` (`i` now equals `3`)

`i <= 2` (condition is `FALSE`, so break)

Using the `<=` operator when your control variable starts at `0` causes an extra iteration to occur, since there are three integer values of `i` such that `0 <= i <= 2` (`0`, `1`, and `2`). To ensure that there are only two iterations, use the `<` operator, and now the loop will only be executed for values in the domain `0 <= i < 2` (`0` and `1`).

If you are still bent on using the `<=` operator and are fine with a non-zero-based iteration count, then you can simply change the initial value of `i` to `1` to offset the error.

By the way your code is written, I assume that you wish for your inner loop to run 10 times, not 11. This would explain why you are getting an extra iteration, and the issue is quite unrelated to the use of `number_format`. If you are only getting 10 iterations when you don't use that function, you might want to make sure that the statement `1 == 1` evaluates to true in your PHP interpreter.

Additionally, as a code styling issue, I would recommend using consistent case in your statements; you write `foreach` (lowercase) but also use `For` (uppercase). The convention is to use lowercase for both.

I have no clue why you would be only getting 10 iterations without `number_format`. You might be counting incorrectly? Try changing it to `<` and see if that resolves your issue.